# Crear secuencia de numeros con python

Tags: python, numpy

Cómo se podrían crear las siguientes secuencias de números en python?

```
idx_1 = [0, 1, 8, 9, 16, 17]
idx_2 = [0, 1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 16, 17, 18]
```

Las condiciones que se han de cumplir para conformar la secuencia dependen de tres parámetros: *strides*, *i_s* y *f_s*. El código que he realizado por el momento es através de un bucle for:

```
strides = 1 # Incremento entre los valores
f_s = (3,4) # Tamaño del filtro -> Ventana
i_s = (8,8) # Tamaño de la imagen de entrada
cont = np.zeros(np.prod(f_s), dtype=np.int32) # Array contenedor
# Se recorre para cada fila del filtro
for i in range(f_s[0]):
    cont[i*f_s[1]:(i+1)*f_s[1]] = (np.arange(i * i_s[0], i * i_s[0] + strides + f_s[1] - 1))
```

Con numpy.arange() solo es posible incrementar por cada valor, no por parejas, por ejemplo.

¿Existe alguna función específica para esto en python y/o numpy?

Comment: Hola, Diego. ¿Cuál sería la condición de la secuencia que necesitas?

Comment: Hola Adrian, voy a replantear la cuestión, un momento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que se resuelve con un doble rango de números. Por ejemplo:

```py
idx_1 = [i for j in range(0,17,8) for i in range(j,j+2)]
idx_2 = [i for j in range(0,17,8) for i in range(j,j+3)]
```